# Where do I put my static HTML and CSS files when migrating my site from Joomla?

Tags: html, css, cms, joomla

I previously made a website with the Joomla CMS. Once it was online, I started over from scratch to re-do my website using only handwritten HTML/CSS (and a little of JavaScript). My question is:

**How can I deploy my new website online, knowing that there is, in my server, several folder/files that belong to Joomla?**

Should I just erase everything and replace it with the new files?

Comment: I just have to comment that I always find statements like this strange. ALL web sites are based on HTML and CSS but so often I see people speak of it as if doing so is different because they're using some software like React or whatever. Yes, I understand the point you are trying to make but it's still strange to me.  I don't think this question is on topic here.

Comment: @Rob I agree that the title they chose was confusing.   However, it is clear from the context that they mean a "static" website and that they have an actual question about deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using Joomla at all, my suggested step is to make a complete backup of the joomla site, *then* delete it and replace it with your files.

If you aren't using Joomla any more then you don't need any of the Joomla core files.

Watch out that you don't delete images or other assets that you may have uploaded and need in the new site.

Answer (score 2):

Typically when replacing a Joomla website, I move all the files and folders in the root folder (e.g. `/public_html`) into a sub folder such as `/public_html/old` which I retain for a few weeks in case I need to retrieve anything I have forgotten about or need to compare the new website to the old website.

If it exists, you should probably leave the `/.well-known` folder in the root folder as this is associated with the SSL certificate. Other files you should leave might include any Google verification files which will look something like `googlece47f0f3211dd73e.html`.

Joomla 3 should still run happily in a sub folder and the only things you usually need to change are the tmp and logs folder paths in the Global Configuration (or edit these manually in the `configuration.php` file.

Answer (score 1):

> several folder/files that belong to Joomla

Do you mean only core files? Or files, which are important fo ruser, like images or pdf?

If you mean only Joomla core or extension files - they may be deleted. But if there are images or documents, which could be important for visitors - try to redirect them, or you will experience a kind of downgrade after switch.

In any case create a redirect map before switching and place your news site in a folder beside of your old site. Then redirect old urls to new urls. So files too - like pdf, 301 them from the old folder to the new one.